# "...putting the proper efforts and funds into it..." or "...putting the proper effort and funds into it..."

Tags: parallelism

Complete sentence: Marketing can be invaluable to your firm, and putting the proper effort and funds into it up-front to ensure that it is done correctly can provide you with substantial benefits.

Since "funds" has an s, should effort also have an s so that they are parallel, or is that unnecessary or incorrect?

Comment: "Effort" can be "efforts" in this sentence, but I think "effort" is more natural. You could change "funds" to "funding" to make both singular. I don't know if parallel plurals are necessary here, but "effort and funds" sounds a bit off to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Two (or more) independent objects of the same verb need not agree in number.